# Wrong understanding of implied vol cannot be linear interpolated

Tags: implied-volatility

There is a well known conclusion that `implied vol cannot be linear interpolated.` But I am not sure this `interpolation` is for strike $K$ or time $T$?

That's definitely true for time. When strike $K$ is fixed, interpolation of implied vols respect to time $T$ can make the `Calendar arbitrage`. Surely we assume the interpolation points satisfy the no arbitrage condition.

But is it true when time $T$ is fixed, interpolation of implied vols respect to strike $K$ can make a arbitrage.

I really struggled for related problems, can anyone give me a precise answer?